# How to get dynamic page's id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a HOC which redirects user to login if there is not token. And what i want to achieve is to store url which user intended to visit before redirecting and push him back to that page. But the problem is in HOC I get only `/product/[id]` but not `/product/1`.

withAuth.ts :

```
import { TokenService } from '@/api/tokenService';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';

type TWithAuth = {
    WrappedComponent: JSX.Element;
};

export function withAuth<T extends TWithAuth = TWithAuth>(
    WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>,
): React.ComponentType<T> {
    const InnerComponent = (props: T) => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const Router = useRouter();
            console.log(Router);
            const accessToken = TokenService.getAccessToken();

        if (!accessToken) {
            Router.replace('/auth/login');
            return null;
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }

    return null;
};

InnerComponent.displayName = `withAuth(${WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name}`;

return InnerComponent;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `/product/[id]`? You can use `router.asPath` on the client-side to retrieve the actual path: `/product/1`.

Comment: i get `/product/[id]` everywhere in result of userRouter() call

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are not using server-side rendering (getServerSideProps).
Then, you need to persist state between requests on the client-side (browser)

These are the steps:

- When a user lands on the page and is not logged in, persist the original page request to a cookie or local storage.
- Redirect to login
- Login user.
- When a user is logged in successfully, check the cookie,
- If there is a cookie (or local storage), take the data (original URL)
- Delete the cookie
- Redirect to the original page.

Comment: no i am not. actually i read your post about protecting routes it pretty good. but i cant access dynamic part of the route. (no SSR for me in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the useRouter hook inside an if statement, which breaks the first rule of hooks.

Also,

Try:

```
export function withAuth<T extends TWithAuth = TWithAuth>(
    WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>,
): React.ComponentType<T> {
    const InnerComponent = (props: T) => {
        const Router = useRouter();
        useEffect(()=> console.log(Router), []);
        const accessToken = TokenService.getAccessToken(); // is it async? If so, maybe it should be wrapped inside useEffect

        if (!accessToken) {
            Router.replace('/auth/login');
            // no need to return null, you are already redirecting
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: nope, query params is empty

Comment: is there any way of doing this using middleware?